# Snapshot from the map in android

Tags: android, maps, location, snapshot

I  want to make a snapshot of a particular location from the map by calling intent or from a mapview.Can anyone help me.I am not getting the snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://stuckinaninfiniteloop.blogspot.com/2012/01/saving-map-images-in-android.html) post, I believe this should help. It involves enabling the drawing cache and forcing it use that cache. Usually works on all views. Should work on `MapView` aswell

Code from the link

```
 private Bitmap getMapImage() {  
        /* Position map for output */  
        MapController mc = mapView.getController();  
        mc.setCenter(SOME_POINT);  
        mc.setZoom(16);  

        /* Capture drawing cache as bitmap */  
        mapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapView.getDrawingCache());  
        mapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);  

        return bmp;  
    }  

    private void saveMapImage() {  
        String filename = "foo.png";  
        File f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);  
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);  

        Bitmap bmp = getMapImage();  

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);  

        out.close();  
    }
```